# How to check if the elements of an array are in sequential order in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to know if the elements of an array are in sequential order in elixir. What I have so far

```
arr=[4,2,3,1]
arr2=[3,8,1,7]


Enum.each arr2, fn(x) ->

end
```

I want to print true if it is in sequential order. In this case it would be true since arr1 is in sequential order. Arr2 would print false since its not in sequential order. I have struggled with figuring this out as there are no loops in elixir.

Comment: `Enum.each/2` is an iterator, returning `:ok`. One cannot retrieve _any_ information from it, its sole purpose is to iterate to produce side effects.

Comment: I'm confused. "since arr1 is in sequential order". There is no `arr1`. Maybe you meant `arr`? But then `4,2,3,1` is not sequential by any definition I know. Please clarify what you mean by sequential.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it by writing your own short recursive function, ie:

```
  def check([_x]), do: true
  def check([head | tail]) do
    if head < hd(tail), do: check(tail),
    else: false
  end
```

I'm pretty sure it can be even done even shorter/easier than this :) Just pass your lists in there (please bear in mind that there are no arrays in Elixir):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,1,5]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

iex()> check(list1)
false

iex()> check(list2)
true
```

However, as Aleksei wrote in one of the comments - it's very beneficial to try to solve puzzles like that by yourself ;) I recommend playing with Elixir at [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) :) Good luck!

PS

Please let me know if you would need an explanation of my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Enum.sort(mylist) == mylist
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there's an array that's like arr=[4,2,3,1], even though its not in order it is in random sequential order

Comment: This solution might be easily extended to support reverse order: `Enum.sort(mylist) == mylist or Enum.sort(mylist) == Enum.reverse(mylist)`.

Comment: @compscigirl My advice would be to extend the recursive solution I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684717/2035262) to train yourself in recursion. Reviewing answers does not help much to learn, writing the code does.