# How to check if an array is in sequential and consecutive order in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to know if there's a way I could find out if an array is in sequential order and consecutive. For example

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Arr would return true since it is sequential and consecutive

```
arr2=[1,2,3,4,56]
```

This would return false since 56 does not come right after 4. I have tried so many ways but it is difficult as there are no loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the elements of an array are in sequential order in elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681743/how-to-check-if-the-elements-of-an-array-are-in-sequential-order-in-elixir)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the case when helpers are not as straightforward as plain old good bare recursion. Also, it’s a great exercise because one cannot do [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) without having a clear understanding how to deal with what recursion brings to the table.

```rb
defmodule Checkers do
  def seq?(input), do: do_seq?(input, nil)

  defp do_seq?([], _), do: true # we are done
  defp do_seq?([h | t], nil),
    do: do_seq?(t, h)           # entry
  defp do_seq?([h | t], ah) when ah == h - 1,
    do: do_seq?(t, h)           # success path
  defp do_seq?(_, _), do: false # ouch! we failed
end

Checkers.seq?([1, 2, 3, 4])
#⇒ true
Checkers.seq?([1, 3, 3, 4])
#⇒ false
```

---

Absolutely correct [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3), suggested by @peaceful-james does basically exactly this [under the hood](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.4/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L3773-L3776). The more succinct version of this solution would be

```rb
Enum.reduce_while(arr, true, fn
  curr, prev when prev == true or curr == prev + 1 ->
    {:cont, curr}
  _curr, _prev ->
    {:halt, false}
end) # returns truthy value if seq
```

Answer (score 4):

Just adding one for the record, which is fairly close to Aleksei's recursion but without the helper function and the extra param:

```
  def seq?([]), do: true
  def seq?([_]), do: true
  def seq?([i1, i2 | rest]) when i2 - i1 == 1, do: seq?([i2 | rest])
  def seq?([_ | _]) , do: false
```

Comment: Like. The last clause does not actually need a non-empty list match `def seq?(_), do: false`.

Comment: Indeed, I just kept it as a form of type checking to let it raise a `FunctionClauseError` on non-lists, but it is not necessary for the logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
[1,2,3,4,56] 
|> Enum.chunk_every(2, 1, :discard) 
|> Enum.all?(fn [x,y] -> y == x + 1 end)
```

should do what you ask for with a couple of standard library functions.

`chunk_every` gives you a sliding window that transforms your list to `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 56]]` giving the sequential base for the next check below.
The discard part is removing the single element at the end, i.e. `[1,2,3] |> Enum.chunk_every(2, 1) == [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3]]`, the `:discard` option will leave out that last (single) item (see docs for [`Enum.chunk_every/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/4).)

Then with [`Enum.all?`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2) and the given filter function you check if every pair is consecutive.

Comment: This produces a superfluous intermediate list though, which might be memory-consuming on huge lists.

Comment: Best answer IMO. Replace `Enum.chunk_every` with `Stream.chunk_every` to avoid the intermediate list.

Comment: I benchmarked all 4 solutions (plain recursion, `Stream.chunk_every`, `Enum.chunk_every` and `Enum.reduce_while`) with a list that contains 1 to 100,000. The plain recursion version takes about 670 microseconds, which is the fastest. The `reduce_while` version comes the second with about 2550 microseconds. The other 2 are on par with about 22,000 microseconds, which is way slower than the plain recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enum.reduce` with an initial value being a tuple `{true, nil}` representing `{"is the list still consecutive and sequential?", "the last element processed by reduce"}`.

```elixir
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

{is_consecutive_and_sequential, _last_element} =
  Enum.reduce(arr, {true, nil}, fn
    current, {true, nil} when is_integer(current) -> {true, current}
    current, {true, previous} when is_integer(current) -> {current == previous + 1, current}
    current, {_anything, _previous} -> {false, current}
  end)
```

If you are going to have a very long list, you can use `Enum.reduce_while` for a more efficient solution:

```elixir
{is_consecutive_and_sequential, _last_element} =
  Enum.reduce_while(arr, {true, nil}, fn
    current, {true, nil} when is_integer(current) ->
      {:cont, {true, current}}

    current, {true, previous} when is_integer(current) ->
      if current == previous + 1,
        do: {:cont, {true, current}},
        else: {:halt, {false, current}}

    current, {_anything, _previous} ->
      {:halt, {false, current}}
  end)
```

Comment: You don’t actually need to keep anything but `previous` in the accumulator; once the sequence breaks you already have `:halt` on hand to return falsey value.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** with humble inclusion of Aleksei's correction

Here is another way using `Enum.with_index`

```
    myList = [2,3,4,5,56]
    [head | _] = myList                         # gets first element in the 'array'
    res= Enum.with_index( myList, head) |>      # so [{2,2},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5},{56,6}]
         Enum.all?(&match?({x,x}, &1))
   if res == 1 do
       "sequential"
    else
       "not sequential"
    end
```

Comment: `myList |> Enum.with_index(head) |> Enum.all?(&match?({x,x}, &1))`

Comment: It’s not an improvement, it’s a correct solution unlike yours which returns `"sequential"` for `myList = [1,2,4,3]` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using std functions (probably more expensive though)

```
defp consecutive?(list) do
  [h | tl]= d = Enum.sort(list)
  d == Enum.to_list(h..List.last(tl))
end
```